# MVC practices. Service within another service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, service

`Service1` injects `Repository1`. `Service2` injects `Repository2`.

Suppose two different scenarios:

1)
Some method of `Service2` needs to retrieve data from `Repository1`.
Should `Service2` inject `Service1` or `Repository1` when both of them provide respective `get()` method?

2) Some method of `Service1` at it's end should call another method from `Service2`. Is it a bad practice to inject `Service2` to `Service1` for such needs? Is it a good practice to use event listen techniques like AOP for such needs?

Answer (score 15):

There are many factors to consider here when we talked about best practices.

As a good start, try to understand the concept of [SOLID](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEMQFjAGahUKEwiM3tvL_pTIAhUSBY4KHX5mCjE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSOLID_(object-oriented_design)&usg=AFQjCNGNe2yaWleUYOnAmd7f5KYFycRvUw&sig2=H_2r19dtEZ65Uc6VYw8l8Q) principles.
Generally, it is good to have multiple classes with very focused roles that calls the other rather than combining all functionalities in one class. High reusability and least code duplication which in turn gives maintainability.

**For scenario 1.)**

It is perfectly fine to have a service calling another service if that business code defined in the method is the same business functionality needed by the other service. This follows the **DRY** principle, no redundant codes.

But it is also perfectly fine to just directly call the Dao from a service instead of calling a different service to do that for you if it is just a simple call with no further business logic. Especially if the two services are in the same module anyway, there is no strong reason to make another service a bridge class for an obvious **simple single line** of code unless you want to abstract it, but in your case, its just a simple get call.

**For scenario 2.)**

But another thing to consider is **modularity** and **direction of dependency**. If each service calls each other, there could be problem in your design, as much as possible avoid **circular dependency** on different modules because this could lead to **spaghetti** code, better to extract same code to a different class declared on common module that can be shared by many modules.

Final note, as what Robert Martin says, you won't be able to code at once the cleanest code in one round. Best codes are forged by continuous refactoring and code cleanup. To quote Robert Martin,

> The Boy Scouts have a rule: **"Always leave the campground cleaner than you found it."**

Answer (score -1):

I am not greatly experienced with this problem, but personally I would avoid coupling controllers. My first approach would be trying to create an interface that would fit all models if possible. It would then be possible to create a model that wires multiple models together to access the data you need without adding references to the controller. For instance:

```
Model1 implements iModel{}
Model2 implements iModel{}

ModelWrapper implements iModel{
    private iModel model1;
    private iModel model2;

    public ModelWrapper(iModel model1, iModel model2)
    {
        this.model1 = model1;
        this.model2 = model2;
    }

    public SomeDataType getSomeValue(){
        SomeObject.param1 = model1.method();
        SomeObject.param2 = model2.method();
        return SomeObject;
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to approach the number of models passed into the constructor and also a way to search each model for the data you are looking for. If the data is not found a null reference or better a custom error could be thrown. If the implementation is consistent perhaps the wrapper could combine all models and allow access to many custom combinations. At least this way, when requirements change you can simply add an additional wrapper to get what you need without changing the current implementation.

Perhaps a more experienced developer will build on my response to provide you a better implementation, but I hope this helps.

Comment: You should not bloat an interface or class with many roles or even set of different data jut because you want to use a single model across your application, it highly breeds spaghetti code thus software ROT. To embrace change, follow the principles encouraged by software gurus and experienced developers.Such principles are SOLID, DRY, YAGNI, Domain Driven Design, Clean code architecture, etc.

Comment: Would it not be a desired design if the database interfaces could all support the same operations? My thought was generic interfaces used to access each entity. In that way you could create a facade to access across multiple interfaces and still use this as a single reference. I am interested in your solution, could you please provide an example?

Comment: As a quick answer, common operations should be indeed abstracted to prevent redundant code and normally generics is used for this one, though reflection can also be used with the overhead of course. Same abstraction can be used for Models via inheritance and composition.
Well you could create another post for this question, since it is totally a different topic.